# Leaflet координаты

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, leafletjs, mapbox

Подскажите, как я могу получить координаты углов каждого тайла?

```
                var layers = {
                    Streets: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets'),
                };
                layers.Streets.on('tileload', function (e) {
                    ... как-то получить координаты углов загрузившегося тайла ...
                });
```

Версия leaflet 0.7.7. Благодарю!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В обработчик события `tileload` передается объект `{tile: ... , url: ... }`. Элемент `tile` является HTML элементом `<img />` с некоторыми допольнительными параметрами. Один из них `_leaflet_pos` - отступ в пикселах от левого верхнего угла видимой части карты (поскольку параметр начинается с подчеркивания, подразумевается что он приватный, его не будет в документации и он запросто может называться в другой версии иначе или вообще отсутствовать). Также эти значения можно увидеть в параметре inline-стиля `transform`. Чтобы перевести пикселы в координаты, можно воспользоваться методом [`layerPointToLatLng`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-layerpointtolatlng). Например так:

```
layers.Streets.on('tileload', function (e) {
    console.log(mymap.layerPointToLatLng(e.tile._leaflet_pos));
});
```

См также:

1. Исходник [`L.TileLayer`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v0.7.7/src/layer/tile/TileLayer.js#L562)

Comment: А как я могу найти координаты верхнего левого угла?

Comment: Так вот как раз они и получатся на выходе `mymap.layerPointToLatLng(e.tile._leaflet_pos)`. Если понадобятся другие углы, то в пиксельных координатах нужно будет прибавлять размер тайла, потом переводить в угловые.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде все получилось

```
var layers = {
                Streets: L.mapbox.tileLayer('mapbox.streets'),
            };
                    layers.Streets.on('tileload', function (e) {
                        var topLeft = map.layerPointToLatLng([e.tile._leaflet_pos.y, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x]);
                        var topRight = map.layerPointToLatLng([e.tile._leaflet_pos.y, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x + layers.Streets.options.tileSize]);
                        var downLeft = map.layerPointToLatLng([e.tile._leaflet_pos.y + layers.Streets.options.tileSize, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x]);
                        var downRight = map.layerPointToLatLng([e.tile._leaflet_pos.y + layers.Streets.options.tileSize, e.tile._leaflet_pos.x + layers.Streets.options.tileSize]);
                        L.marker([topLeft.lat, topLeft.lng]).addTo(map);
                        L.marker([topRight.lat, topRight.lng]).addTo(map);
                        L.marker([downLeft.lat, downLeft.lng]).addTo(map);
                        L.marker([downRight.lat, downRight.lng]).addTo(map);
                    });
```

Может это можно было сделать как-то более изящно... И странное поведение появилось - отрисовывается только половину маркеров почему-то... [image: http://image.prntscr.com/image/c42fb1b161b74a55babce747a9d38355.png]